# How can I turn values in my Doubly Linked List into a string?

Tags: java, string, function, doubly-linked-list, sentinel

I have created a class `SLList` where I take in a doubly linked list `SLList` where the input can be of any generic type. In order to aid myself in doing this, I've implemented sentinels to help me.

However, now, I need to find how to turn my Doubly Linked List into a string via method `turntostring()`

Here is my code so far...

```
public class SLList<T>{
    private class IntNode {
        private T data;
        private IntNode previous;
        private IntNode next;

        public IntNode (T data, IntNode previous, IntNode next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
            this.next = next;
        }



        public IntNode () {
            next = previous = this;
        }
    }
    public int size = 0;

    IntNode sentinel;

    public SLList(){
        sentinel = new IntNode();
    }


    public String turntostring() {
        String S = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            S += x;
        }
        return S;
```

However, I'm struggling to understand how an I supposed to turn Doubly Linked List values into strings. My attempt so far has been yielding an error. Can anyone please help explain this to me?

Comment: What is a sentinel?

Comment: Any (subclass of) `Object` (which your `T` is) can be turned into a `String` using the (inherited) `toString` method. Iterate over each node and append the return value of `toString` the node's `data` field.

Comment: The key here is to iterate over all the `IntNode` elements that have been chained together. Loop until the current node's `next` is `null`, assuming you build your list correctly.

Comment: so like, for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {x.toString()} return x .... ?

Comment: that only loops over the index values from `0` to `size-1`. You want `for(IntNode current = start; current!=null; current=current.next)` where `start` ist the head of your list.

Comment: and then I do current.toString?

Comment: it woild be really nice if u could maybe write out ur code and maybe provide an explaination alongside it if you can

Answer (score 1):

Few things I will recommend

1. Improve your variable naming scheme, like you have used a sentinel
   name which sounds illogical in this context.
2. The logic is also a bit incorrect, you haven't added an addNode method which can be problematic.

I have corrected the code and which I will mention here. Do let me know if you have any problems.

```
public class SLList<T> {
    public int size = 0;
    IntNode head, tail = null;

    // DoubliLinkedList Element - IntNode
    private class IntNode {
        private T data;
        private IntNode previous;
        private IntNode next;

        public IntNode(T data, IntNode previous, IntNode next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public IntNode() {
            next = previous = this;
        }

        public IntNode(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public void addNode(T data) {
        // Create a new node
        IntNode newNode = new IntNode(data);

        // If doubly list is empty
        if (head == null) {
            head = tail = newNode;
            // head's previous will point to null
            head.previous = null;
            // tail's next will point to null, as it is the last node of the list
            tail.next = null;
        } else {
            // newNode will be added after tail such that tail's next will point to newNode
            tail.next = newNode;
            // newNode's previous will point to tail
            newNode.previous = tail;
            // newNode will become new tail
            tail = newNode;
            // As it is last node, tail's next will point to null
            tail.next = null;
        }
    }

//  public SLList() {
//      sentinel = new IntNode();
//  }

    public String turnTostring() {
//      String S = "";
//      for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
//          S += x;
//      }
//      return S;
        IntNode current = head;
        if (head == null) {
            return "Empty DLL";
        }
        String list = "null <==> ";

        while (current != null) {
            list += current.data + " <==> ";
            current = current.next;
        }
        list += null;
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SLList<Integer> dl1 = new SLList<Integer>();
        dl1.addNode(3);
        dl1.addNode(34);
        dl1.addNode(36);
        dl1.addNode(333);

        String turnTostring = dl1.turnTostring();
        System.out.println(turnTostring);

    }
}
```

Comment: I also suggest to remove that `next = previous = this;` int `IntNode`'s constructor as it makes no sense at all. Also rename `IntNode` since it holds generic values and that name is probably a leftover from non-generic times.

Comment: Also don't initialize `String list` with `"null <==> "`, what's the point of that? And the trailing `list += null;`?

Comment: Yes, that's also a bit illogical, I have kept IntNode just to make him/her understand, It's better to go with the Node as it's generic.

Comment: I have added "null <==> " at both ends to give a visual representation of a doubly liked list, as head.previous and tail.next will be null.

Comment: Suman those null values are not part of the data of the list though. These `null`s are used to represent the end of the list, there's no point in including these in the output.

Comment: Yes if you think from a data perspective you are right but think from an Object reference perspective, then I think appending null is okay. Anyway, It's just a String representation so It's your choice how you show your data structure.

Comment: But you are not supposed to print object references, you want to print the string representation of the `data` in each node. There is no data at the start of the end at the list, there is not even a node there.